Why is a conductive nose a desirable feature for stealth aircraft?
Recently I saw this illustration that lists the desirable characteristics of a stealthy plane.
Most of them make sense but I did not understand how a conductive nose could help the plane be more stealthy.
The conductive canopy part I searched and I got some conflicting information but overall that seems to be simple.
What's this conductive nose for? Wouldn't that make it more obvious?

Source

Not sure why this was down voted, seems like a reasonable on-topic question.

Do you have the source of the picture?

It's a prototype diagram from here https://www.secretprojects.co.uk/threads/blitzfighter-bushwacker-atlas-lightweight-attack-studies.9179/

Atom ionization occurs naturally at the nose due to air friction. It also occurs at any location directly facing the airflow, like the leading edges. A ionized material behaves like a shield for electromagnetic waves:

Radar waves from the outside are reflected to the outside. This makes the tracking by hostile radars easier by reinforcing their echos.

Radar waves from the inside are reflected inside. This prevents the aircraft from hosting its own radar antenna in the nose.


To hide from external radars and/or to use the nose as a radome, ionization has to be eliminated. In both cases this is done using a conductive material.
Details follow.

Radar is based on wave bouncing
Radar is based on wave reflection/refraction, detected as an echo. Materials with better reflective/refractive properties, like ionized ones, create stronger echos. Hiding from radars means not using such materials.
Ionization by friction, de-ionization by current
When the aircraft moves through air, electrons are ripped off atoms by friction (material and air atoms), leaving ionized atoms at the material surface and in air around and free electrons. De-ionizing atoms consists in making atoms neutral again. It's done by capturing free electrons circulating in the materials.
But free electrons, which is nothing else than what we call "current", move only in conductive materials, hence the material subject to ionization must be conductive to allow the circulation of free electrons and their recapture by ionized atoms.
Aircraft areas more subject to ionization are the ones directly facing the airflow, leading edges and nose.
Conductive radome material
Nose is often used for the radar antenna. The material here must allow radar waves to be radiated and received, preventing pure metal to be used, but at the same time must allow electrons to circulate, i.e. it must be conductive. The material used for this part, the radar dome, or radome, is actually high technology, there are many electromagnetic constraints to be taken into account. For more, see Why do Russian Su-30SM fighters have white nose radomes?
